# IOS Android images

Tags: android, iphone, ipad

I'm currently working on a website and I would love to use some of the appstore images on my webpage. Would you guys know if there is any issues if I used the images from itunes and the android market?

Comment: What do you mean by "appstore images"? Do you mean the Google Play and iTunes logos? Do you mean download buttons referencing each? Here's a [page on branding from Google](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/brand.html) that might address some of your questions on the Google Play side if so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an issue with that because both markets have these images for "Download on Market", maybe you can even have the code for this on your developer site on each market.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the images that you bought from these stores, then there is no problem using it on your website. 
And if you are trying to use images or banners that is displayed on these stores which are not meant for selling may require owner permissions legally.